# How to check the length of file which is inside the zip file

Tags: bash, shell, zip, unzip, file-length

I want to check files inside the zip are not empty. I know the `unzip -l` command but it gives lot of information.

```
[abc@localhost test]$ unzip -l empty_file_test.zip
Archive:  empty_file_test.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
    0      07-05-2017 06:43   empty_first_20170505.csv
    0      07-05-2017 06:43   empty_second_20170505.csv
---------                     -------
    0                         2 files
```

I extracted the file names from the zip file by command

```
file_names="$(unzip -Z1 empty_file_test.zip)
file_name_array=($file_names)
file1=${file_name_array[0]}
file2=${file_name_array[1]}
```

I tried using `-s` option but not useful

```
if [ -s $file1 ]; then
   echo "file is non zero"
else
   echo "file is empty"    
fi
```

It always prints `file is empty` even though file is not empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
unzip -l empty_file_test.zip | awk 'NR>=4{if($1==0){print $4}}'
```

may work for you, which could also be written as

```
unzip -l empty_file_test.zip | awk 'NR >= 4 && $1==0{print $4}'
```

Comment: Thanks. Both the solutions worked for me. Also, I am able to store empty files into an array. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could format the output fo unzip -l

```
unzip -l test.zip | awk '{print $1 "\t"  $4}' | tail -n+4 | head -n-2
```

Explanation:

`unzip -l` unzips the files and returns the deisred information

`awk '{print $1 "\t"  $4}'` prints columns 1 and 4 (size and filename)

`tail -n+4` strips the first few lines from the output (removing the header and unwanted information)

`head -n-2` strips the last two lines from the output (removing the unwanted summary)

**Edit:**

To store empty files into an array you can map the output of the comand:

```
read -r -a array <<< `unzip -l test.zip | awk '{print $1 "\t"  $4}' | tail -n+4 | head -n-2 | awk '{if($1==0) print $2}'`
```

Explanation

`unzip -l test.zip | awk '{print $1 "\t"  $4}' | tail -n+4 | head -n-2` is explained above

`awk '{if($1==0)}{print $2}'` just gives you the filenames of the empty files

`<<<` inputs the output of the command in backticks `` into the read command

`read -r -a array` reads the input into the variable array

**BUT**

You could just use the shorter command of Sjsam and do the same:

```
read -r -a array <<< `unzip -l empty_file_test.zip | awk 'NR>=4{if($1==0){print $4}}'`
```

`read -r -a array` is explained above

`<<<` is explained above

`awk 'NR>=4{if($1==0){print $4}}'`

- `NR>=4` puts out every line > 4 (strip the header and unwanted output)
- `if($1==0){print $4}}` if the size ($0) is 0 it executes `{print $4}`
- `{print $4}` outputs the filename

Comment: Thanks for explanation provided +1. What should I do to store empty files in a array?

Comment: I've added an edit to the post to answer your question.